# not sure on how to add a delete function to my mern app using API's

Tags: reactjs, mern

i am fairly new to coding and dont fully understand how to incorporate a delete function and button in my react app, can someone please show me how or point me to a website that can help.

This is my contactslist.js

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


const Contact = props => (
    <tr>
        <td className = { props.contact.contact_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.contact.first_name}</td>
        <td className = { props.contact.contact_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.contact.last_name}</td>
        <td className = { props.contact.contact_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.contact.email}</td>
        <td className = { props.contact.contact_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.contact.mobile}</td>
        <td>
            <Link to={"/edit/" + props.contact._id}>Edit</Link>
        </td>
    </tr>
)


export default class ContactsList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            contacts: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/contacts')
            .then( res => {
                this.setState({
                    contacts: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch( err => console.log(err));
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/contacts')
            .then( res => {
                this.setState({
                    contacts: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch( err => console.log(err));
    }

    contactList = () => this.state.contacts.map(
        (contact, index) => <Contact contact={contact} key={index} />
    )


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Contacts List</h3>
                <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20}}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { this.contactList() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My edit contact-list.js

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class EditContact extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            first_name: '',
            last_name: '',
            email: '',
            mobile: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/contacts/' + this.props.match.params.id)
            .then( res => {
                this.setState({
                   first_name: res.data.first_name,
                    last_name: res.data.last_name,
                    email: res.data.email,
                    mobile: res.data.mobile
                })
            })
            .catch( err => console.log(err));
    }

    onChangeFirstName = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            first_name: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeLastName = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            last_name: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeEmail = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            email: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeMobile = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            mobile: !this.state.mobile
        });
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const obj = {
           first_name: this.state.first_name,
            last_name: this.state.last_name,
            email: this.state.email,
            mobile: this.state.mobile
        };
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/contacts/update/' + this.props.match.params.id, obj)
            .then( res => console.log(res.data));

        this.props.history.push('/');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Update Contacts</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>First Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.first_name}
                                onChange={this.onChangeFirstName}
                                />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.last_name}
                                onChange={this.onChangeLastName}
                                />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Email: </label>
                        <input type="text" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
                                />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Mobile: </label>
                        <input type="number" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.mobile}
                                onChange={this.onChangeMobile}
                                />
                    </div>
                        <br />
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update Contact" className="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

my delete-contact.js. this is where im getting lost. am i suppose to do this in my edit-contacts.js or do i create a delete-contacts.js file?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

export default class DeleteContact extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.deleteContact = this.deleteContact.bind(this);
    }

    deleteContact() {
        axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/contacts/delete-contact/' + this.props.obj._id)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('Contact successfully deleted!')
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.obj.first_name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.obj.Last_name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.obj.email}</td>
                <td>{this.props.obj.mobile}</td>
                <td>
                    <Link className="edit-link" to={"/edit-contact/" + this.props.obj._id}>
                        Edit
                    </Link>
                    <Button onClick={this.deleteContact} size="sm" variant="danger">Delete</Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

when i try to link my delete-contact file to my app.jsfile, i get this message in the browser

```
C:/Users/seanv/node_modules/@restart/context/forwardRef.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\Users\seanv\node_modules\@restart\context'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your delete-contacts.js file last_name is misspelled here `<td>{this.props.obj.Last_name}</td>` .

Comment: thank you i fixed it but it still does not help me, i need to figure out how to make this delete function work in my task

Answer (score 0):

You can write your delete in `edit-contacts.js` or `delete-contacts.js` it is your choice if you are beginner to MERN i'd recommend to code it in simpler way below i  have put sample code for delete.

```
ViewUser.js

import React,{Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import UserItem from "./UserItem";


export default class ViewUser extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getAllUsers = this.getAllUsers.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            User : []
        };
    }

    getAllUsers(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({User: response.data});
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(this.getAllUsers,2000)
    }

    UserItem(){
        return this.state.User.map(function(object, i){
            return <UserItem obj={object} key={i}  />;
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3 align="center">User List</h3>
                <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>e-mail</th>
                        <th colSpan="2">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    { this.UserItem() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`UserItem.js`This contain delete

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class UserItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
    }
    delete() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/delete/' +this.props.obj._id)
            .then(console.log("User Deleted"))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {this.props.obj.FirstName}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.obj.LastName}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.obj.Address}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.obj.Gender}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.obj.email}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <Link to={"/update/"+this.props.obj._id}>Edit</Link>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onClick={this.delete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

export default UserItem;
```